# Log file avoid dumping sql query data in it.. c shell

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, logging

I have sql script "example.sql":

```
SPOOL &1
Select '<.TR>'||'<.TD align="left">'||column_name||'<./TD>'||'<.TR>' from table1;
spool off
```

which dumps it contents to cshell script "getdata.csh" this is how i get data from sql script to csh script

```
sqlplus $ORA_UID/$ORA_PSWD @${SQL}example.sql ${DATA}${ext}
```

My problem is when I run my job to do this it dumbs all data extracted from sql query in log file too.. How can I avoid dumbing data into log files. What do I have to do in this code to do so? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here for information about your issue: [sqlplus spool](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/spool.html)

Essentially, you will need to add these two settings:

```
set echo off
set termout off
```

Comment: if i do termout off can i retrive output in ${DATA}${ext} or it will completely stop dumping query output

Comment: please read that link, it answers the question directly, with links to explain both of these.